# Whats the difference bewteen zerg and cheaper

Tags: uwsgi

It seems that `cheaper` and `zerg (with broodlord)` do much the same thing: that is spawning additional workers when needed.

What is the difference, and why would I use one and not the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With cheaper you choose the max number of processes an instance could spawn, no way to modify it without changing the config and reloading.

Zerg mode allows you to run new instances (even with a different config) attached to the same socket used by an already running instance.

This allows various forms of autoscaling.

Comment: I follow [this](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#the-zerg-dance-pausing-instances) to use the zerg dance, and tried both `echo Q > /var/run/running.fifo` with `echo p1 > /var/run/sleeping.fifo` and `echo 1p > /tmp/running.fifo` with `echo 2p > /tmp/sleeping.fifo` from this [doc](http://daniellombrana.es/blog/2015/07/01/gracefulreloading.html), but none of them work. Do you have any suggestions? Or should I open I new question?

Comment: This is my post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42895774/uwsgi-zerg-dance-rollback-resume-unpause-method